# Random Sample With replacement

Tags: c++, random

I draw a blank here: How do you sample with replacement in `C++` (not using boost), but all members of `std::` are ok. I mean what is the approach (or the function if we can twist a member of `std::` to do this).

To provide some context, I want to sample (with replacement)  `k` elements from  an array `Data[n]` of `n` doubles.

Comment: @jamesdlin: this is for sampling *without* replacement right?

Comment: @AmiTavory: Oops, you're right.  I mixed up the meaning of "without replacement" and "with replacement" since the Fisher-Yates shuffle replaces the randomly selected item.

Comment: Isn't this trivial, am I missing something?With replacement: if your vector has *n* elements, just select *k* times a random number between *0* and *n-1*, take those elements.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given a function `random_num_in_range` (more on that later), it shouldn't be that hard to roll your own sampler:

```
// Samples randomly from (b, e) into o, n elements
template<typename It, typename OutIt>
void sample(It b, It e, OutIt o, size_t n)
{
    // Number of elements in range.
    const size_t s = std::distance(b, e);
    // Generate n samples.
    for(size_t i = 0; i < n; ++i)
    {
        It it = b;
        // Move b iterator random number of steps forward.
        std::advance(it, random_num_in_range(s));
        // Write into output
        *(o++) = *it;
    }
}
```

You'd use it possibly like this:

```
vector<int> input;
...
vector<int> output;
sample(input.begin(), input.end(), back_inserter(output), 100);
```

The question is how to write `random_number_in_range` without contemporary  libraries. I suggest you look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10984974/why-do-people-say-there-is-modulo-bias-when-using-a-random-number-generator), but skip past the accepted answer (which I've flagged for moderator attention, as I believe someone edited it into something completely wrong).

Comment: That's fine: random_number_in_range can be obtained from std:: (c++11)

Comment: so `random_num_in_range(s)` produces a random integer in [0,s-1]?

Comment: Yes, that is what it should do.